# I have to show multiple image all will be clickable on android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-gridview

I am making an android application on a library which will look like this [image]

I need to put all those book dynamically and all should be individually clickable after clicking a single book it will be open through default pdf reader.

My problem is using list view is it possible if not then what will be suitable approach.And please show me some example I can't find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/shelves/. A project by Romain GUy. Worth having a look at the project.

http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/browse/trunk/Shelves/src.
http://shelves.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Shelves/. Its a read only. open the trunk and copy the code and use the same.

Use a gridview.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html

Universal Image Loadeer.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.

It is based on Lazy List(works on same principle). But it has lot of other configurations. I would prefer to use Universal Image Loader coz it gives you more configuration options. You can display a error image if downlaod failed. Can display images with rounded corners. Can cache on disc or memory. Can compress image.

In your custom adapter constructor

```
  File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(a, "your folder");

  // Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
  imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
  // Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
  ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
  // You can pass your own memory cache implementation
 .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
 .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
 .enableLogging()
 .build();
 // Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
  .showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//display stub image
  .cacheInMemory()
  .cacheOnDisc()
  .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
  .build();
```

In your getView()

```
  ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
  imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);//provide imageurl, imageview and options.
```

You can configure with other options to suit your needs.

Along with lazy loading/Universal Image Loader you can view holder for smooth scrolling and performance. http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html.

Edit:

https://github.com/androidnerds/shelves. Link to download as zip.

Comment: Please give the link of that source code that project I can't be able to download it please give the download link

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/shelves/source/checkout. Non members can check only readonly. By the way you unaccepted the answer?

Comment: It saying Command-line access

Use this command to anonymously check out the latest project source code:

# Non-members may check out a read-only working copy anonymously over HTTP.
svn checkout http://shelves.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ shelves-read-only

Comment: http://shelves.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Shelves/AndroidManifest.xml. Opened manifest.http://shelves.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Shelves/src/org/curiouscreature/android/shelves/ShelvesApplication.java

Comment: Can u please download the code and upload that into http://www.megafileupload.com/

Comment: i gave you a link. I can't do that sorry. U need to copy paste the code from the link for each file. Any reason for unacepting the answer after accepting it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27068/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-bumba)

Comment: check the edit above. A clone of romain guy's project posted by someone.